# How to locate "other" files on an Imac

Tags: hard-drive, imac, disk-utility, storage

When I look at my available disk space on my imac it says ive used 700 gigs for "other" files. How do i find these files and delete them?

Answer (score 1):

I use a app called [OmniDisk Sweeper](http://www.omnigroup.com/more).

It allows me to find all files and delete the one I do not want.

In case of a application I use the [AppCleaner application](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) that not only deletes the app but all associated stuff with it.

Comment: Just to clarify, Mac uses "other" for all files that do not fit the preset category! (that is sometimes confusing.

Comment: Oh ok so that means the space is not necessarily unavilable??

Comment: Correct :) it is bit misleading but that is what it says.